# What are "Enumerate subkeys" and "Notify" permissions in Registry?

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-registry

What are "Enumerate subkeys" and "Notify" permissions in the registry and what they allow to do?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783530(v=ws.10).aspx this explains all,the current state of question is too broad to explain could u elaborate with specific things

Comment: Thanks, but i want to know what does EXACTLY do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"Enumerate subkeys"** is pretty much self-explanatory – it allows **listing the names of all subkeys** inside the given key, using the [RegEnumKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724861(v=vs.85).aspx) function. (A "key" in Windows Registry terminology is like a folder.) So if you have this permission on `HKLM\Software`, then you're allowed to see the names below it – `HKLM\Software\Adobe`, `HKLM\Software\Microsoft`, etc.

**"Notify"** is described in @Vignesh4303's linked documentation as "**request change notifications** for registry keys or subkeys". That is, your programs are allowed to use  [RegNotifyChangeKeyValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724892(v=vs.85).aspx) and related functions, and be notified by Windows when another program makes any changes to that part of the Registry.